# SQLAlchemy: Child not automatically associated with parent in one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'm facing an issue with SQLAlchemy where the child object in a one-to-many relationship is not being automatically associated with its parent when using the ORM.

Here is a simplified version of my Classes:

```py
class Schedule(BaseModel, Base):
    # ... (other attributes)

    routes: Mapped[List['Route']] = relationship(back_populates='schedule', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class Route(BaseModel, Base):
    # ... (other attributes)

    schedule_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('schedules.id'), nullable=False)
    schedule: Mapped['Schedule'] = relationship(back_populates='routes')
```

When I create and save a new **Route** object, it is not automatically added to the **schedule.routes** list. I've ensured that the relationship is correctly configured with the **back_populates** and **cascade** attributes.

Is there anything specific I should check or configure to ensure that the child object is automatically associated with the parent in this one-to-many relationship?

```py
def test_relationship_between_schedule_and_route(self):
        # Create the first route
        route1 = Route(
            schedule_id=self.schedule.id,
            route_number=123,
            departure_terminus="terminus1",
            arrival_terminus="terminus2"
        )
        route1.save()

        # Get the schedule and the first route
        retrieved_schedule = storage.get("Schedule", self.schedule.id)
        retrieved_route1 = storage.get("Route", route1.id)

        # Additional print statements for debugging
        print()
        print("Routes in retrieved_schedule:", retrieved_schedule.routes)
        print("Number of routes in retrieved_schedule:", len(retrieved_schedule.routes))

        # Ensure the first route is associated with the schedule
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_schedule.routes, [retrieved_route1])
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_route1.schedule, retrieved_schedule)

        # Create the second route
        route2 = Route(
            schedule_id=self.schedule.id,
            route_number=456,
            departure_terminus="start",
            arrival_terminus="end"
        )
        route2.save()

        # Get the schedule again
        retrieved_schedule2 = storage.get("Schedule", self.schedule.id)
        retrieved_route2 = storage.get("Route", route2.id)

        # Additional print statements for debugging
        print()
        print("Route 1 parentID:", retrieved_route1.schedule_id)
        print("Route 2 parentID:", retrieved_route2.schedule_id)

        # Print information about the actual routes in retrieved_schedule2
        print()
        print("Routes in retrieved_schedule2:")
        for route in retrieved_schedule2.routes:
            print(f"- Route ID: {route.id}, Route Number: {route.route_number}")

        print("Number of routes in retrieved_schedule2:", len(retrieved_schedule2.routes))
        
        # Explicitly add the new route to retrieved_schedule2.routes
        retrieved_schedule2.routes.append(retrieved_route2)

        # Ensure the second route is added to the schedule
        self.assertEqual(len(retrieved_schedule2.routes), 2)

        # Additional checks for the second route
        
        self.assertIn(retrieved_route2, retrieved_schedule2.routes)
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_route2.schedule, retrieved_schedule2)
```

I get the following output:

```
Routes in retrieved_schedule: [<models.route.Route object at 0x7fce72587d00>]
Number of routes in retrieved_schedule: 1

Route 1 parentID: 8fd4f085-b090-4556-abf4-3c80c7f41886
Route 2 parentID: 8fd4f085-b090-4556-abf4-3c80c7f41886

Routes in retrieved_schedule2:
- Route ID: 76a7d817-4225-4061-b14e-d84df46c6c22, Route Number: 123
Number of routes in retrieved_schedule2: 1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.364s
OK
```

Surprisingly, when I create and save **two** new **Route** objects, they are automatically appended to the **schedule.routes** list.

Is this behavior expected in a one-to-many relationship, or could there be a specific reason behind this automatic association? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

```py
def test_relationship_between_schedule_and_route(self):
        # Create the first route
        route1 = Route(
            schedule_id=self.schedule.id,
            route_number=123,
            departure_terminus="terminus1",
            arrival_terminus="terminus2"
        )
        route1.save()

        # Create the second route
        route2 = Route(
            schedule_id=self.schedule.id,
            route_number=456,
            departure_terminus="start",
            arrival_terminus="end"
        )
        route2.save()


        # Get the schedule and the first route
        retrieved_schedule = storage.get("Schedule", self.schedule.id)
        retrieved_route1 = storage.get("Route", route1.id)
        retrieved_route2 = storage.get("Route", route2.id)

        print()
        print("Routes in retrieved_schedule:", retrieved_schedule.routes)
        print("Number of routes in retrieved_schedule:", len(retrieved_schedule.routes))

        # Additional print statements for debugging
        print()
        print("Route 1 parentID:", retrieved_route1.schedule_id)
        print("Route 2 parentID:", retrieved_route2.schedule_id)

        # Print information about the actual routes in retrieved_schedule2
        print()
        print("Routes in retrieved_schedule2:")
        for route in retrieved_schedule.routes:
            print(f"- Route ID: {route.id}, Route Number: {route.route_number}")
        
        # Ensure the first route is associated with the schedule
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_schedule.routes, [retrieved_route1, retrieved_route2])
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_route1.schedule, retrieved_schedule)
        self.assertEqual(retrieved_route2.schedule, retrieved_schedule)

        # Ensure the second route is added to the schedule
        self.assertEqual(len(retrieved_schedule.routes), 2)
```

I get the following output:

```
Routes in retrieved_schedule: [<models.route.Route object at 0x7f62493c6d00>, <models.route.Route object at 0x7f62493c6a60>]
Number of routes in retrieved_schedule: 2

Route 1 parentID: 5b7263a3-d925-4172-8ab8-5461fd0633d1
Route 2 parentID: 5b7263a3-d925-4172-8ab8-5461fd0633d1

Routes in retrieved_schedule2:
- Route ID: 5fad9d79-c9de-4e4f-89b2-b9fa91239d0b, Route Number: 123
- Route ID: 835bb5f8-f3b7-4e1e-b3a7-ecb17a1b4364, Route Number: 456
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.514s
OK
```